# Capture inputs a form inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a way I can capture the inputs in a form inside an iframe before its being submited?

```
<iframe src="fromanothersite.com" />
```

I am trying to get the inputs in the iframe

Comment: You can't. Please read about [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this could lead to attacks such as [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking), which is why browsers enforce the same-origin policy as security measure.